# How to install map reduce plugin on eclipse luna on Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce

i have sucessfully installed hadoop 2.6.1 on my ubuntu system.
i want to run mapreduce program of wordcount on eclipse luna,so can someone help me installing mapreduce plugin on eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first the hadoop version must be as same as ur hadoop plugin for the eclipse 
and then open ur diretory of ur eclipse u will see the dropin diretory put ur hadoop plugin for  eclipse luna to dropin diretory  open ur eclipse windows preferences click the hadoop map/reduce select the hadoop2.6.1 of windows  bless u